# What is the English name for the palm's spots of the "working hands"?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

People who are used to going to the gyms, after sometime they get thick skin in the palm — under each finger — because they work with their hands a lot.

What are these hard spots called in English?

[image: Hand with hardened skin]

When I put the word callus into my dictionary it showed me the same meaning as "warts", because we call "wart" everything on the skin that is hard, even-though there are big differences between them and the locations are different.

n.b. No specific word for it in my language, therefore I can not see the translation on a dictionary.

Comment: [Callus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/callus?s=t)

Comment: How are you supposed to look up "palm's spots on working hands" in the dictionary? There is no way this should be closed as "answerable by a dictionary".

Comment: @ColleenV I would think in the OP's native language there would be a word or an expression for this, and then translating it into English would be fairly straightforward thing to do. How do you think the majority of NNS do this, in the beginning of their road to learning?

Comment: Actually, unlike English, there is no specific name for this in my language (at least I don't know about it...). I'm not that dummy or lazy and before I ask here questions I always look for the alternatives.

Comment: There is no word for the hard skin under the soles of your feet in your language? The hard skin on hands are not exactly the same thing, but they are very closely related. BTW I haven't voted to close your question.

Comment: Ok, I understood your suspicion but you can ask before judging:) By the way when I put the word callus into my dictionary it showed me the same meaning as "warts", because we call "wart" everything on the skin that is hard, even-though there are big differences between them and the locations are different.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't disagree that adding information about the translation would make the question better, but this is not a "quick dictionary lookup". Translations are a good place to start, but often aren't entirely accurate.

Comment: @ColleenV I was merely responding as to how someone would begin their research using a bilingual dictionary. If the term doesn't exist in the OP's native language how am I supposed to know unless they actually mention it? I have no problems with the question, I edited the post when I saw the previous edit had made things worse.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry - I wasn't really directing that at you, but rather the folks that might be voting to close this without providing any guidance or feedback at all. I think that asking for clarification from the author in these situations instead of throwing a close vote at them is the right thing to do. I was rushing and conflated the close vote with your comment and they're really two separate things. Your question brought out information that I think makes this post much better, so I'm not criticizing you at all.

Comment: Well, `callus` and `wart` have very similar definition: "hard spot on the skin". They only differ in source: Warts are result of infection while calluses are result of physical damage.

Comment: +1 for including a picture, that makes the question immediately clear

Comment: @ColleenV I didn't want to belabour the point because the question has been answered,  but... Googling these simple terms ["hard skin" hands](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22hard+skin%22+hands) would have provided an answer. Just saying!!

Comment: @Mari-LouA [Ask even if the answer exists online](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/65) Just because an answer can be found elsewhere doesn't mean that the question shouldn't be asked. Some might look at the answer and think that's not much more than a dictionary would say, but the way the question is phrased is what is more helpful I think. If I search for phrases from the question like *define thick skin palms* or *working hands* with DuckDuckGo a clear answer doesn't come up. It's a shame though that there is only one answer here - it would be nice if all our questions had at least 2.

Comment: @ColleenV EVERY answer can be found online, but some are easier to unearth than others. Yes, two or more answers would be nice, but if the answer is callus, what more can one add? Hard skin? Not a corn? Callus is derived from Latin?  A person can be described as being *callous* (spelled with an "o")? Absolute Beginner could have provided more detail, but that's the answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I just don't see the answer to this as that easy to find if you don't already know it. Absolute's answer is fine (26 people thought enough of it to up-vote!) I just think it's helpful to have different voices. This isn't the greatest question for a lot of diversity because the answer is quite simple if you know it, but looking over the question and what Industrious has said about the term in their first language, I might think about explaining the difference in English between a callus and a wart and whether it is still a callus if it's not on a hand or foot. Stuff like that.

Answer (score 32):

The term is ***[callus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/callus)***: (plural calluses)

> - a hard and thickened area on the skin and especially on the hands or feet

(M-W)

Usage example:

> - *He was a migrant handyman with no calluses*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48796/discussion-on-answer-by-absolute-beginner-what-is-the-english-name-for-the-palm).